# Convert byte array represented as hexadecimal string to correct int

Tags: java, arrays, hex, byte, buffer

I have a byte array,

[102, 100, 51, 52, 48, 48]

Which has the hex string representation:

"fd3400"

Which if I convert it to a number, shows as being 16593920.

However, when I convert it using the snippet below

```
int iSec = ByteBuffer.wrap(bSec).order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN).getInt();
```

I get the result: 875783270. The bytes are supposed to be in LSB format, but I can't seem to get the correct value out, as 875783270 != 16593920. I'm getting kind of confused with these data formats.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Byte array contains the byte representation of a **string**.

In [ASCII](http://www.asciitable.com/):

- 102 == 'f'
- 100 == 'd'
- 51 == '3'
- 52 == '4'
- 48 == '0'

You should convert from byte array to string and then parse that string using base 16 (hexadecimal).

```
String hex = new String(arr, "ASCII"); //fd3400
int number = Integer.valueOf(hex, 16).intValue(); //16593920
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, this has indeed gotten me one step closer to the solution! :) I'm now dealing with a new problem though, the hex string appears to be inverted due to the LSB format. Will simply flipping the string before trying to parse it suffice?

Comment: The hex string is the same as you mentioned in the question. Here is the working code. http://ideone.com/g7oMLr. I'm not sure about what are you asking? If you have any other question, please post it in another thread.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I meant that instead of "fd3400" I'm looking to extract the value of "0034fd".

Comment: What is the final number (int) you are looking for?

Comment: That would be 13565. Another example: H:7e3900 -> D:14718 and H:0309 -> D:2307

Comment: Yes. Then reversing the String might get you there.